# Trouble with Jquery for each and $(this), I can't reference one element

Tags: jquery, function, loops, foreach, this

I am currently having trouble jquery I'm trying to trigger an event where when the user clicks on the header of an article, the hidden paragraph snippet is displayed under it fades in, my problem is every time I click on one header all of the paragraphs show under all the other headers how can I just trigger the paragraph for the header I click on? Here is the HTML code :

```
    <div id="content">
    <div class="column">
    <div class="Article">
    <img src="images/SteveJobs.png" alt="Steve Jobs" Title="SteveJobs" />
    <h1><a href="#"> Computers changed Forever</a></h1>
    <p> The Brilliant Mind of Steve Jobs. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="Article">
    <img src="images/Cannibal.png" alt="Cannibal" Title="Randy Cannibal" />
    <h1><a href="#"> Face-Eating Cannibal Attack May Be Latest in String of 'Bath Salts'        Incidents</a></h1>
    <p> On May 26, Miami police shot and killed a homeless man who was allegedly feasting on the face of another homeless man in a daylight attack on a busy highway.  </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('.Article h1 a').click(function() {
     $('.Article p').each(function() {
         $(this).fadeIn(3000).show();
            });
           });
         });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.Article h1 a').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $(this.parentNode).next('p').fadeToggle(3000);
     // $(this).closest('.Article').find('p').fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't know I can reference the next element this way. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() { 
                $('.Article h1 a').click(function() {
                   $(this).parent().next().fadeIn(3000);
               });
          });
         </script>
```

Comment: Cool, I just learned some new stuff, awesome thanks a bunch, I am very grateful.